# How to instantiate class in Java where number of parameters in constructor of class under test is unknown through Reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

Using Reflection in Java, I want to instantiate a class where number of parameter in constructor is unknown. Can it be done?

Comment: Do you mean it's using `varargs` ? If not, if you don't know the number of parameters, how will Java know which contructor to use? Take a look at [`java.lang.Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) getConstructors().

Comment: You can query for all possible constructors and choose one of them, is that what you need? Please clarify and give an example.

Comment: If you don't know the *number* of constructor parameters, let alone their types, how are you supposed to supply values for them?

Comment: Reflection is used as a tool to test classes, so the Class Under Test can be anything, with any constructor type, so how do we instantiate them as we are not aware what are the classes that can be tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Constructor[] ctors = Test1.class.getDeclaredConstructors();
 for (Constructor constructor : ctors) {
        System.out.println(constructor);
 }
```

If you test you will see that all constructors are showed, with there parameters and which object you need to pass.

To have the paramets types do:

```
 Class[] clz = constructor.getParameterTypes();
```

So I guess the answer is Yes.